# I'm getting nil error with image?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, uiimageview, iboutlet

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

i'm getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
imagedata is not nil it has a value of 2604750 bytes 
I don't know why it show this error as I can see img1 is nil why ?
any comments !!!

```
@IBOutlet var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var img2: UIImageView!
// in viewWillAppear I gave it a default image
self.img1.image = UIImage(named: "dummy.png" )
self.img1.image = UIImage(named: "dummy.png" )

// i changed to send the nsmanagedobject but it's still same error

func setimage(person: NSManagedObject){
let data: NSData = NSData()
if person.valueForKey("picture") as! NSData == data{
if person.valueForKey("tag") as! Int == 1 {
img1.image = UIImage(named: "dummy" )
}else if person.valueForKey("tag") as! Int == 2 {
img2.image = UIImage(named: "dummy")

}}
else{
if person.valueForKey("tag") as! Int == 1 {
img1!.image = UIImage(data: person.valueForKey("picture") as! NSData )
}else if person.valueForKey("tag") as! Int == 2 {
img2.image = UIImage(data: person.valueForKey("picture") as! NSData )

}
}

}
```

Comment: Your UIImageView is nil (img1)

Comment: so what do you think should I do ? @DavidSkrundz

Comment: Initialise it before you try to set it's image. somewhere in your code you should do this: img1 = UIImageView()

Comment: I did it and I Initialize it with default image that in my project but it still shows error @Woodstock

Comment: @Fahad post the actual code and the new error message

Comment: I added set image method will get the person from another view controller @Woodstock

Comment: did you connect your outlet for img1?

Comment: yes @AndriyGordiychuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a simple mistake. In fact your outlets were nil. However, not because you did not assign them in the storyboard, but because the `setimage` was called on a different instance of `ViewController`.

You have a property `view1` in your second view controller which is declared as:

```
let view1: ViewController = ViewController()
```

This creates a NEW instance of `ViewController`. When you then call `view1.setimage` you get a crash because outlets for THIS instance are not connected.

The property in your second view controller should be

```
var view1: ViewController!
```

and in your `imageTapped` method of the `ViewController` you should modify code so it has this line:

```
view.view1 = self
```

Forced unwrapping might not be ideal, but it should work as long as you ensure that whenever you instantiate your second view controller you set the `view1` property.

Comment: I really appreciate it. now it works as it supposed to be thanks a lot. @AndriyGordiychuk

Answer (score 0):

I think is the same thing as Andriy is suggesting.  Probably your Outlet for the image is not connected with the view.

Comment: `@IBOutlet var img1: UIImageView! ; @IBOutlet var img2: UIImageView!` it's connected

Comment: Sorry to bother you but would be possible to check the connections in Interface Builder because I had issue before even when my code says @IBOutlet, in the connections was showing they were not connect so i have to reconnect them again.

Comment: I've deleted and reconnected  again but still same error I don't what's going on @JuValencia

Comment: @Fahad upload your code on GitHub. There must be some easy to fix error but it is really hard to spot it without running the code

Comment: i uploaded it as a zip folder, it's under  [link](https://github.com/falmasmoum/acs560_course_project) @AndriyGordiychuk

Comment: @Fahad and what should I do to replicate your error? I cannot find a way to set the new image for the contact

Comment: if you close the app and run it again the picture will appear for the contact because if you go to viewWillAppear it will execute from there it gets it from the core data but in setimage method doesn't  something strange @AndriyGordiychuk

Comment: @Fahad if I reopen the app I still see a dummy image :) I probably need to assign a contact but I do not know how to do it :)

Comment: because you haven't chose image for the contact in Contacts for the iPhone simulator @AndriyGordiychuk

Comment: @Fahad I am running on the phone. How do I tell the app to use a specific contact?

Comment: just tap on any picture and the popover view will appear click button and chose contact who has a picture @AndriyGordiychuk

Comment: @Fahad when I press on some contact the page opens with details of that contact and I do not see any "Use this" button :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92199/discussion-between-fahad-and-andriy-gordiychuk).

Answer (score 0):

Your outlets are nil, there are a couple of reasons why this could happen.

1. They have not been connected in the interface builder.
2. You are accessing them before they have been instantiated, e.g. before viewDidLoad() has been called.